# how to separate string by comma and store inside a string

Tags: php

I have a string like this
'a,b,c' i need to convert this as " 'a','b','c' "

I have tried this by `explode` but this is put it inside an array

```
$keys = explode(",", $key);
```

Comment: I have mentioned it already like it should be " 'a','b','c' "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `explode`, then `implode` to required format:

```
echo "'" . implode("', '", explode(',', $key)) . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that. Probably the fastest one liner would be:

```
$keys = '\''.str_replace(',', '\',\'', $key).'\''
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some other example

Code:

```
$string =   'a,b,c';

$array1 =   explode(',',$string);

foreach($array1 as $val){

    $array2[]   =   "'".$val."'";

}

$array2 =   implode(',',$array2);

print_r($array1);

print_r($array2);


Out Put:

Array
(

    [0] => a

    [1] => b

    [2] => c

)

'a','b','c'
```